# Solving and manipulating non linear equations

Tags: equation-solving

my problem is the following. I have two functions of the kind f1(k) and f2(k) which are also functions of some parameters. I would like to know to see how the k such that f1(k)=f2(k) changes as the parameters' values change and I would also like to know how the value of the functions f1 and f2 change with the parameters' values when evaluated in the equilibrium (f1(k)=f2(k)). 
The two functions are

```
f1(k)= 1-((((\[Sigma]o*(1-\[Theta]o))^(\[Sigma]o))/((\[Sigma]y(1-\[Theta]y))^{\[Sigma]y}))*(((((1-\[Sigma]o)(1-\[Eta]o))^{(1-\[Eta]o)*(1-\[Sigma]o)-\[Eta]y*(1-\[Sigma]y)})*((\[Sigma]o*(1-\[Theta]o)+(1-\[Sigma]o)*(1-\[Eta]o))^{\[Eta]y*(1-\[Sigma]y)+\[Eta]o*(1-\[Sigma]o)-1}))/((((1-\[Sigma]y)*(1-\[Eta]y))^{(1-\[Eta]y)*(1-\[Sigma]y)-\[Eta]o*(1-\[Sigma]o)})*((\[Sigma]y*(1-\[Theta]y)+(1-\[Sigma]y)*(1-\[Eta]y))^{\[Eta]y*(1-\[Sigma]y)+\[Eta]o*(1-\[Sigma]o)-1})))*((\[Alpha]*\[Beta])^(1/\[Mu]))/(\[Alpha]*(1+n))*(k^((\[Alpha]-1)/\[Mu]))*(1-\[Alpha]-(1+n)*(k^(1-\[Alpha]))))^{1/(1-\[Eta]y*(1-\[Sigma]y)-\[Eta]o*(1-\[Sigma]o))}
```

and `f2(k)=((1-\[Mu])*(1-\[Alpha])*(1/(\[Sigma]y*(1-\[Theta]y)+(1-\[Sigma]y)*(1-\[Eta]y))))/(\[Mu]*(1-\[Alpha]-(1+n)*(k^(1-\[Alpha])))+(1-\[Mu])*(1-\[Alpha])*(1/(\[Sigma]y*(1-\[Theta]y)+(1-\[Sigma]y)*(1-\[Eta]y))))`

I have tried with this code

```
Manipulate[Solve[{1-((((\[Sigma]o*(1-\[Theta]o))^(\[Sigma]o))/((\[Sigma]y(1-\[Theta]y))^{\[Sigma]y}))*(((((1-\[Sigma]o)(1-\[Eta]o))^{(1-\[Eta]o)*(1-\[Sigma]o)-\[Eta]y*(1-\[Sigma]y)})*((\[Sigma]o*(1-\[Theta]o)+(1-\[Sigma]o)*(1-\[Eta]o))^{\[Eta]y*(1-\[Sigma]y)+\[Eta]o*(1-\[Sigma]o)-1}))/((((1-\[Sigma]y)*(1-\[Eta]y))^{(1-\[Eta]y)*(1-\[Sigma]y)-\[Eta]o*(1-\[Sigma]o)})*((\[Sigma]y*(1-\[Theta]y)+(1-\[Sigma]y)*(1-\[Eta]y))^{\[Eta]y*(1-\[Sigma]y)+\[Eta]o*(1-\[Sigma]o)-1})))*((\[Alpha]*\[Beta])^(1/\[Mu]))/(\[Alpha]*(1+n))*(k^((\[Alpha]-1)/\[Mu]))*(1-\[Alpha]-(1+n)*(k^(1-\[Alpha]))))^{1/(1-\[Eta]y*(1-\[Sigma]y)-\[Eta]o*(1-\[Sigma]o))}==((1-\[Mu])*(1-\[Alpha])*(1/(\[Sigma]y*(1-\[Theta]y)+(1-\[Sigma]y)*(1-\[Eta]y))))/(\[Mu]*(1-\[Alpha]-(1+n)*(k^(1-\[Alpha])))+(1-\[Mu])*(1-\[Alpha])*(1/(\[Sigma]y*(1-\[Theta]y)+(1-\[Sigma]y)*(1-\[Eta]y))))},k],{\[Sigma]o,0.0001,0.9999},{\[Sigma]y,0.0001,0.9999},{\[Eta]o,0.0001,0.9999},{\[Eta]y,0.0001,0.9999},{\[Theta]o,0.0001,0.9999},{\[Theta]y,0.0001,0.9999},{\[Alpha],0.0001,0.9999},{\[Beta],0.0001,0.9999},{n,0.0001,0.9999},{\[Mu],0.0001,0.9999}]
```

But I have two problems: 1) mathematica starts running but then it stops without solutions (aborted); 2) I think Solve cannot give me the value of the function but only of the k such that f1(k)=f2(k) so maybe Solve is not the right command.

Any guess?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

1: You are misusing {expr} which should be (expr). {} and () mean completely different things to Mathematica. Fix all those

2: FindRoot seems to do better than solve

```
Manipulate[FindRoot[1 - ((((\[Sigma]o*(1 - \[Theta]o))^(\[Sigma]o))/
((\[Sigma]y (1 - \[Theta]y))^\[Sigma]y))*(((((1 - \[Sigma]o) (1 - \[Eta]o))^
((1 - \[Eta]o)*(1 - \[Sigma]o) - \[Eta]y*(1 - \[Sigma]y)))*((\[Sigma]o*(1 -
\[Theta]o) + (1 - \[Sigma]o)*(1 - \[Eta]o))^(\[Eta]y*(1 - \[Sigma]y) +
\[Eta]o*(1 - \[Sigma]o) - 1)))/((((1 - \[Sigma]y)*(1 - \[Eta]y))^((1 -
\[Eta]y)*(1 - \[Sigma]y) - \[Eta]o*(1 - \[Sigma]o)))*((\[Sigma]y*(1 -
\[Theta]y) + (1 - \[Sigma]y)*(1 - \[Eta]y))^(\[Eta]y*(1 - \[Sigma]y) +
\[Eta]o*(1 - \[Sigma]o) - 1))))*((\[Alpha]*\[Beta])^(1/\[Mu]))/(\[Alpha]*
(1 + n))*(k^((\[Alpha] - 1)/\[Mu]))*(1 - \[Alpha] - (1 + n)*(k^(1 - 
\[Alpha]))))^(1/(1 - \[Eta]y*(1 - \[Sigma]y) - \[Eta]o*(1 - \[Sigma]o))) ==
((1 - \[Mu])*(1 - \[Alpha])*(1/(\[Sigma]y*(1 - \[Theta]y) + (1 - \[Sigma]y)*
(1 - \[Eta]y))))/(\[Mu]*(1 - \[Alpha] - (1 + n)*(k^(1 - \[Alpha]))) + (1 -
\[Mu])*(1 - \[Alpha])*(1/(\[Sigma]y*(1 - \[Theta]y) + (1 - \[Sigma]y)*(1 -
\[Eta]y)))), {k, 1}], {\[Sigma]o, 0.0001, 0.9999}, {\[Sigma]y, 0.0001, .9999},
{\[Eta]o, 0.0001, 0.9999}, {\[Eta]y, 0.0001, 0.9999}, {\[Theta]o, 0.0001, 0.9999},
{\[Theta]y, 0.0001, 0.9999}, {\[Alpha], 0.0001, 0.9999}, {\[Beta], 0.0001, 0.9999},
{n, 0.0001, 0.9999}, {\[Mu], 0.0001, 0.9999}]
```

3: You might find lots of tiny complex parts because of all your exponents. You might try wrapping Chop[ ] around your expression inside the FindRoot[] to discard the tiny complex parts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for the k, even though I have these tiny imaginary parts. Two more things please: 1) I should write Manipulate[Findroot[Chop[expression],...],...] to eliminate them? 2) Is there a way to have the value of the expressions as well and not only of the "k's" that make them equal?

Comment: @FabioCerina Try `Manipulate[{f1=..,f2=..,Chop[Findroot[f1==f2,{k,1}]},..]` but the `Chop` will not eliminate "large" complex parts, only very very small. Read the help page for `Manipulate` and try to learn all the details.

Comment: Thanks we are getting very close! I've added a ] which I think it was missing to close the Chop command. The only problem now is that I don't get the value of f1 and f2 in numerical terms as the one I get for k. I get something like {1 - 0.000848558 ((0.357 - 1.462 k^0.357)/
    k^0.986188)^2.37424, 0.451035/(
 0.451035 + 0.362 (0.357 - 1.462 k^0.357)), {k -> 0.0192722}}. Maybe I should add another option to FindRoot? Thanks again

Comment: Nope...Unfortunately this doesn't work. Complex parts are not a big deal, I am more interested in finding a numeric solution for f1 and f2 thanks